# How to route angular inside docker container?

Tags: angular, docker, angular-routing

I want to deploy my angular app inside a docker container but I'm unable to route my app inside the container. I tried to follow the [official angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration) guidlines. You can have a look of what I did here:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:latest as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . . 
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod


# Stage 1: serve app with nginx server
FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=build /app/dist/pointeuse  /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**Nginx configuration file**

```
server {
  listen [::]:80;
  sendfile on;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   256;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

**Pointeuse folder (my app)**

```
3rdpartylicenses.txt                 polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js
assets                               polyfills-es5.9e286f6d9247438cbb02.js
favicon.ico                          runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js
index.html                           runtime-es5.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js
main-es2015.df94aaa439cec2ec9350.js  styles.4333e01ba2bdd733ca4e.css
main-es5.df94aaa439cec2ec9350.js
```

Comment: I've just done this for the petclinic-angular app: https://github.com/BryanDollery/petclinic/tree/master/petclinic-client maybe that will help

Comment: Hello, I tried to tweak my configuration file again and I got this error from nginx: The connection was reset and if I try to curl localhost I got: connection reset by peer

Comment: How are you running the container?

Comment: I use docker container run -p 80:80 <mycontainer>

Comment: Try using 8080 on the host: -p 8080:80...

Comment: This is exactly the same result: The connection was reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add

```
listen 80
```

in the nginx configuration file.
Because IPv6 is not enabled by default in docker.